# EF Model First : System.InvalidOperationException - Mapping and metadata information could not be found for EntityType

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have **EF Model First** ObjectContext namely *PositionContext*. There is a Entity *PairTrade*. All works fine so far.

Introduced an interface *IPairTrade*, which is implemented by entity *PairTrade*. Now, upon initializing *PositionContext* instance, get following error:

> System.InvalidOperationException: Mapping and metadata information
>   could not be found for EntityType
>   'VSS.PositionManager.BusinessLogic.IPairTradeEntity'

Is there a way I can ask EF to ignore this interface?

Comment: Can you post the relevant code?

Comment: Does you context now have `DbSet<IPairTradeEntity>` or `DbSet<PairTrade>`? It needs to be the latter.

Comment: @VidmantasBlazevicius I am using EF Model First and not Code First. i.e. My context is auto generated by EF.

Comment: @VidmantasBlazevicius : Thanks for directing me in right direction. I have implemented Repository pattern for the given Entity. I am using interface instead of the class. This seems to be the problem. Invetigating.